# In an Asp.net project using identity v2 and Entity Framework how can I move all my code first models and User model identity to a new project

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have a web API 2 project and I use Entity Framework code-first models which has some foreign keys to identity version 2 users table that is bound to webapi 2 project. Since I have another provider project I have a reference to provider in my service (web api 2) project and since provider needs a reference to models putting models in service project cause circular reference.

Long story short I need to be able to move the code first models to a new project called `Models` to be used in both project. The problem is that no matter how hard I tried I couldn't move the `IdentityUser` model to a separate project since it needs reference to `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`

Below is an example of one of the models I use and `ApplicationUser` derives from `IdentityUser`:

```
public class Application
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PaymentInfo { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpireDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Billing> Billings { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well, did you try adding a reference to `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` in the new project?

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes referencing to that needs to import bunch of other assemblies unfortunately. I didn't want my Models project get those references. but I guess thats my only option now. Thanks again.

Comment: If you use NuGet to add the [Entity Framework package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/entityframework) it takes care of adding all the references for you.

Comment: Currently there is no good/simple way to avoid adding EF to your Models project. I've been bitten by that before and there have been numerous questions about it here. So far I have not seen an elegant solution for this problem -((

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue few months ago.

ApplicationUser has to be inherited from IdentityUser. And there is no other way to keep all models of your project in one class library project without using required references when you using Identity framework.

My suggestion is to use separate project (class library) to handle all the identity stuff rather than keeping it on your web API 2 project. Then you can reference that project anywhere when you needed. This will avoid having Web Api 2 project referencing on Models project.

Hope this helps.